# Смена ячейки по свайпу, или по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: objective-c, ios, apple

Есть UITableView которая собрана из кастомных ячеек. Скажем в середине этой таблицы при особых условиях появляется очередная кастомная ячейка в которой должен содержаться например текст. Как сделать чтобы по нажатию на кнопку которая находится в ячейке выше данной происходил свайп ячейки с текстом на такую же ячейку с другим текстом? Само собой то что размер текста разный, а следовательно высота ячейки в которой должен быть текст тоже будет другая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я так понимаю, что с получением сообщения о нажатии проблем нет.

Касательно анимации попробуйте так:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];

[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[cellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

[self updateDataSource];//обновление массива с данными.

[tableView endUpdates];
```

Только не забудьте вернуть правильную высоту для новой ячейки. Важный момент: разные RowAnimations для удаления и вставки.

Comment: Все работает, приходит ячейка с нужно высотой. Только она полностью пустая приходит. Точнее она заполненная, но ничего не отображается. Если смотреть в 3-D отладчике то весь контент в ячейке есть и отображается как надо, а в симуляторе ячейка полностью белая

Comment: Проблема с отображением ячейки скорее всего связанна с кодом самой ячейки (Например, layout как-то не верно отрабатывает во время анимации или drawRect).